# Consultar multiples tablas en Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5

Tengo esta consulta en la que se buscan productos y la categoría a la cual pertenecen:

```
$products = Product::product($product)
                          ->category($category)
                          ->with('category')
                          ->orderBy('id','DESC')
                          ->paginate(7);

return view('mega/product/list', compact('products'));
```

Lo que deseo es consultar la tabla precio en esa misma consulta. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Podrías poner más información, la relación productos, categorías y precio. Quizá los modelos.

Answer (score 2):

Si en el modelo indicas la relación tienes resuelto el problema:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbProductos';
    protected $id='id';

    public $timestamps = false;     //true valor por defecto
    public $incrementing = true;    //true valor por defecto

    public function precio()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('App\Precio');
    }
    ....
```

Con esto puedes usar eloquent para acceder directamente

```
$precio = Product::product($id)->precio()
```

Tienes que tener MUY claro el modelo de datos. Quién es el propietario de la relación y quién es tiene los fk. Es recomendable entender cómo se traduce el modelo a las tablas. También se puede indicar de forma explícita las claves ajenas pero no es necesario:

```
public function precio()
{
     return $this->hasOne('App\Precio', fk_precio);
}
```

**Importante:** Normalmente se hace uso del *lazy loading*. Es decir, sólo se piden los datos cuando se necesitan, lo cual puede generar problemas de rendimiento. Si quieres traer los datos de una tacada hay que indicarlo explicitamente mediante el *eager loading* usando el operador **with**

ver: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

Precio se relaciona con producto?

Porque si es asi podrias usar la relacion con otro foreach, quedaria algo como:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
       @foreach($product->precios as $precios)
           <p>Precios de este producto</p>
            {!! $precios->precio !!}
       @endforeach
@endforeach
```